# Ant Design Pro dynamic menu not showing up

Tags: ant-design-pro

Following the instruction at https://pro.ant.design/docs/router-and-nav#fetch-menu-from-server

I changed file BasicLayout.tsx as below. Menu is not showing up.

```
...
const testMenu = [{name:"login", path:"/user/login"}] as any;
const [menuData, setMenuData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  if (dispatch) {
    dispatch({
      type: 'user/fetchCurrent',
    });
  }
  setMenuData(testMenu)
}, []);
...
menuDataRender={()=>menuData}
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I was doing same as you and failed as you. Document is still wrong.
And I found getting menu from server has a lot of bug with ant design pro v4. (Maybe I did not know)
So my final decision is to display all menu from /config/config.ts as designed initially.
And get only authorization information from server and set only authority to show only logged in user related menu.
So my solution (not correct answer) is:

I referenced this link. https://umijs.org/docs/runtime-config#patchroutes-routes-

Created file `/src/app.tsx` and inserted code as follow:

```
interface PathAndIdsModel {
  path: string;
  ids: string[];
}

const setAuthority = (routes: any, pathAndIds: PathAndIdsModel[]) => {
  routes.forEach((route: any) => {
    const found = pathAndIds.find((item) => item.path === route.path);
    if (found) {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-param-reassign
      route.authority = [...new Set([...(route.authority || []), ...found.ids])];
    }

    if (route.routes) {
      setAuthority(route.routes, pathAndIds);
    }
  });
};

async function patchRoutes({ routes }) {
  const response = await fetch(`https://localhost:44357/authorities`);
  const pathAndIds = await response.json();
  setAuthority(routes, pathAndIds);
}
export { patchRoutes };
```

Inserted following code to ASP.Net Core Controller:

```
        [HttpGet("/authorities")]
        public IEnumerable<object> Authorities()
        {
            return new[]
            {
                new {
                    Path = "/dashboard/analysis",
                    Ids = new [] { "user", "admin", },
                },
                new {
                    Path = "/dashboard/monitor",
                    Ids = new [] { "user", "admin", },
                },
                new {
                    Path = "/dashboard/workplace",
                    Ids = new [] { "admin", },
                },
                new {
                    Path = "/form/basic-form",
                    Ids = new [] { "admin", },
                },
            };
        }
```

`/dashboard/workplace` and `/form/basic-form` page will be hidden if logged in as user, but shows if logged in as admin.

I tried to get full routes from server, but failed because of async call, UmiJS did not wait until fetching from server and setting new routes.
So when I fetched routes from server and changed routes, UmiJS already converted icon and component of old routes and my new routes never changed.